# return unique rows with a tolerance for a matrix

Tags: matlab

I use unique function to find a full rank matrix (unique rows of matrix), now I need to  unique

function  that returns unique rows with  a tolerance. Is there anyone who know how can I do this?

I am gratefule to you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it with `sortrows` (which is what `unique` uses internally):

```
A = [1 2 3; 1 2.1 3; 1.001 2.001, 3.001; -4 5 6] % example data
tol = 0.01; % tolerance
[~, ii] = sortrows(A);
ii_unique = ii(logical([1; any(diff(A(ii,:))>tol,2)]));
A_unique_tol = A(sort(ii_unique),:) % result
```

The result in this example is:

```
A =

    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000
    1.0000    2.1000    3.0000
    1.0010    2.0010    3.0010
   -4.0000    5.0000    6.0000

A_unique_tol =

    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000
    1.0000    2.1000    3.0000
   -4.0000    5.0000    6.0000
```

As usual, for old Matlab versions that don't support `~` as an output argument, change `[~, ii] = sortrows(A);` by `[vv, ii] = sortrows(A);`

Comment: Sorry, but when I run this code, it has error on line 3,(unbalenced )or ]) ,could you please help me?

Comment: @Rosa Maybe you have an old Matlab version which does not support `~` output. Change `[~, ii] = sortrows(A);` by `[vv, ii] = sortrows(A);`

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to define well, assume you have a tolerance of 1.
Then what would be the outcome of `[1; 2; 3; 4]`?

When you have multiple columns a definition could become even more challenging.

However, if you are mostly worried about rounding issues, you can solve most of it by one of these two approaches:

1. Round all numbers (considering your tolerance), and then use `unique`
2. Start with the top row as your unique set, use [`ismemberf`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23294-ismemberf) to determine whether each new row is unique and if so, add it to your unique set.

The first approach has the weakness that 0.499999999 and 0.500000000 may not be seen as duplicates. Whilst the second approach has the weakness that the order of your input matters.